# Tclientsocket if socket can't connect

Tags: delphi, tclientsocket

I want that my sockets connects to an backuphost when the socket can't connect to the host, i tried this:

```
if prclient.Socket.connected = false then
begin
prclient.Active := false;
prclient.Port := PORT;
prclient.Host := HOST;
prclient.Active := true;
prclient.Open;
sleep(500);
if prclient.Socket.Connected = false then
begin
prclient.Active := false;
prclient.Host := BACKUPHOST;
prclient.Active := true;
prclient.Open;
end;
end;
```

But now he doesn't connect at all.
Who knows a working script?

Comment: The IDE doesn't notify you of an ESocketError exception anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the socket in blocking mode then both `Active:=True` and `Open()` (which you SHOULD NOT be using together!) will raise an exception if the connection fails:

```
prclient.Port := PORT;
prclient.Host := HOST;
try
  prclient.Open;
except
  prclient.Host := BACKUPHOST;
  prclient.Open;
end;
```

If you are using the socket in non-blocking mode, then no exception is raised (unless a socket API function fails), the conection is attempted in the background, and you will be notified of the final result via the `OnConnect` or `OnError` event depending on whether the connection succeeds or fails, respectively.